# SyntaxError: invalid syntax, clause on '=' in eval() function

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, eval

I'm having the following trouble with my program:

```
  File "C:/Users/6ixpage/Documents/SoftwareDevelopment/Python/Programs/CLI/PrintandCopy/P&C Job System.py", line 75, in set
    eval('self.details['+a+'].'+b+'"'+c+'"');
  File "<string>", line 1
    self.details[0].file = "image"
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's the code snippet for reference:

```
IN = ('details','0','file','image')
if IN[0] == 'details':
    a = IN[1]
    b = IN[2]
    c = IN[3]
    print('self.details['+a+'].'+b+' = "'+c+'"');
    eval('self.details['+a+'].'+b+' = "'+c+'"');
```

- `IN[0]` - used to identify that the command specifies the details of the folder.
- `IN[1]` - the task within the folder.
- `IN[2]` - the attribute of the task (any of type, file, quantity, tally).
- `IN[3]` - the value to set the attribute to.

The entire code is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_FdEIbU4EzwbXVGOFp4QmZkejQ), unfortunately undocumented as I originally wanted to only have a simple CUI setup. But do quiz me if you have any questions about particular snippets. I have paper documentation too, that shows how the program is supposed to work.

If you can suggest some changes to how the CUI works please do, especially if they will cause less headaches than the one I currently have. (And I'm certain that I don't have to use `eval()` for every single function.)

Comment: `eval` evaluates an expression. Assignment is a statement, not an expression so you can't do it with `eval`. Use the answer from @Jérôme

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Duncan's [comment](/q/42189757/#comment71541452_42189757):

> [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) evaluates an expression. [Assignment is a statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), not an expression so you can't do it with `eval`.

You could use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python#2220790) for the explanation about `exec` and `eval`), but seriously, there is no need to obfuscate your code with these.

Here's what you could do:

```
inputs = ('details', '0', 'file', 'image')
if inputs[0] == 'details':
    a = inputs[1]
    b = inputs[2]
    c = inputs[3]
    setattr(self.details[int(a)], b, c)
```

(Note there is no test. All inputs are considered valid.)

Explanation:

- `int(a)` turns string `'0'` into integer `0`.
- `setattr` sets attribute `'file'` of `self.details[0]` to `'image'`

You should consider `eval` and `exec` last resort things. Most likely you don't need those anywhere in your code.

For instance

```
eval('print(self.' + str(arg) + ')')
```

should be written

```
print(getattr(self, arg))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this change to the program works perfectly and makes it look a whole lot neater ^O^

Answer (score 1):

Assignments are not allowed in the `eval` function; try using `exec` instead.

Comment: exec might work here, but please don't use it when you can write simple code.

Comment: In general, `eval` and `exec` are not to be used; their usefulness is cases where dynamic execution of code from an external source is required.

Comment: As such though, there are all of the risks associated with the arbitrary execution of unvetted code. Also, debugging such code execution (especially errors in the external code) can be a challenge as normal debugging methods may not be available.

(I apologize for the late edit -- accidental submission of original comment.)