# Is there any way I can read a Python pickle (test1.pickle) from Java or Kotlin?

Tags: java, python, dictionary

I have found this page : http://www.picklingtools.com/html/java.html  but I don't understand it very well and I think it's what I am looking. My situation is like this:
-I have to read a python pickle which contains a dictionary with some data that I need to get for my logic I am going to implement in my android project.

Comment: `.py` files aren't pickles. This is a very strange requirement, why are you trying to use python source code as a data serialization format? Just use one of the many cross platform serialisation formats, like JSON

Comment: If you have an ecxecutable python file, which returns the map, you could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887320/get-data-back-from-jython-scripts-using-jsr-223

Comment: Sorry guys, I looked again and I found out that the file I have  to read is .pickle @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unpickle a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616060/how-to-unpickle-a-file-in-java)

Comment: @Rohit Patil  That looks complicated and I can't understand it very well, is there any simple solution ?